# CPU usage of PHP instances

Tags: php, instance, monitoring, ibm-cloud

I have multiple PHP instances on my Bluemix account. With the API service I collected the CPU, memory and disk stats from these PHP instances.
When a PHP instance is very busy, the CPU usage is over 200. This value is also shown in the dashboard of the Bluemix PHP instance.

How is this possible?
Is this because the PHP instance works on multiple CPUs?
If this is so, how can I retrieve the number of CPUs of a PHP instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cpu usage of an application instance can range from 0% (no CPU used) to the number of logical CPUs on the DEA\HOST * 100%
This means that if the application DEA is 2 core CPU, so the cpu usage for app may be 0%~200%.

I found this useful link https://github.com/cloudfoundry/dea_ng/issues/93 where is discussed your same question and seems that you can't retrieve the number of cores.